# Why does ${\rm cov}(Y_{ij}, Y_{ik}) = \sigma_u^2$ in the model $Y_{ij} = \mu + u_i + e_{ij}$?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, covariance

Consider $Y_{ij} = \mu + u_i + e_{ij}$ where $\mu$ is a constant and $u_i ∼ N(0,\sigma_u^2
)$ is the subject $i$ random effect which is independent of the error term $e_{ij} ∼ N(0,σ_e^2)$. I can't figure out why $${\rm cov}(Y_{ij}, Y_{ik}) = \sigma_u^2$$

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well,

$$ {\rm cov}(Y_{ij}, Y_{ik}) 
= {\rm cov}(u_{i} + e_{ij}, u_{i} + e_{ik}) 
$$

since the constant term, $\mu$, does not affect variances or covariances. By the [bilinearity of covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties) we have

$$ {\rm cov}(Y_{ij}, Y_{ik}) 
= 
{\rm cov}(u_{i}, u_{i})
+ {\rm cov}(u_{i}, e_{ik})
+ {\rm cov}(e_{ij}, u_{i})
+ {\rm cov}(e_{ij}, e_{ik})
$$

By independence of $u_{i}$ and each $e_{ij}, e_{ik}$ and independence between $e_{ij}$ and $e_{ik}$ (which must be assumed for this model to make sense), the 2nd, 3rd and 4th terms are all zero above (since [independence between two variables implies that their covariance is 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Uncorrelatedness_and_independence)). So,

$$ {\rm cov}(Y_{ij}, Y_{ik}) 
= 
{\rm cov}(u_{i}, u_{i})
= {\rm var}(u_{i}) = \sigma^{2}_{u}

$$

Comment: To cover the case when $j=k$, you may add a Kronecker delta to Macros's answer: $\mathrm{Cov}[Y_{ij},Y_{ik}]=\sigma^2_u+\sigma^2_e\,\delta_{jk}$.

Comment: or you could just note that $${\rm cov}(Y_{ij},Y_{ij}) = {\rm var}(Y_{ij}) = \sigma^{2}_{u} + \sigma^{2}_{e}$$

Comment: You are right. I'm just pointing a way to make the formula work for every $i,j,k$.